# How to find if a column of items, linked to itemA in another column, have a specific value in a specific column?

Tags: sql-server

So I am not that familiar with SQL yet, with the problem below you will see I lack lots of knowledge but I need help with the following:

I have a product, I'll call it ParentProduct;

It has sub-products - ChildProduct1, ChildProduct2, etc.

I need query that will will bring up all ParentProducts in my DB that have ChildProducts(don't need to return these as a result), which have TRUE in column ColumnPosted.

One of the main issues is that I don't quite know the tables I should be using, as I don't have access to the DB but I need to know if I am doing the right logic.

I have the following(some values may be changed for the sake of security):

```
WHERE 1=1 
 AND Product.ClientID=1
 AND dbo.Products.ProductID IS NOT NULL -- to show the ParentProduct
 AND Products.Status=1 -- to show active products
 AND dbo.Products.ProductID IN (SELECT ChildProductID FROM Products WHERE 
ColumnPosted = "TRUE") -- Here should be the filter checking if the 
--ParentProduct has ChildProducts which are ColumnPosted = True)
```

Comment: First it makes it really difficult to help if you dont know the database structure and cant post it.  Second look into INNER JOIN instead o fusing the IN statement, runs much better

Comment: Can you give the sample data and expected output so it will be easy for us to understand the scenario?

Comment: What would the syntax be with INNER JOIN taking into account the example I have?

Comment: Expected output should be ParentProduct1, ParentProduct 2 and so on, as long as ParentProductX has at least 1 ChildProductX that has ColumnPosted = TRUE.

Comment: Because of this *One of the main issues is that I don't quite know the tables I should be using* we can not be certain of a correct answer.

Comment: @SvetoslavAntonov I am confused do you have only one table or two tables? If you tables I am assuming tableName called ParentProducts and SubProducts? Is that so please clarify. As well as please post a sample table and expected sample table which will be easy to understand.

Comment: wait, is this homework?

Comment: This wasn't homework. But once I got to see the DB structure it was easier than I thought. It's solved now. Thanks all for you help.